# PeerJS Server 404 on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, peerjs

I'm trying to deploy a PeerJS server on Azure. On my kudu console, running

```
node peerjs --port 9000
```

returns

```
Started PeerServer on ::, port: 9000, path: / (v. 0.2.8)
```

However, when I try to connect to the server from my client code, I get a 404. Going directly to *appname*.azurewebsites.net/peerjs/id in my browser also returns a 404.

I see inside their package.json file, they run

```
bin/peerjs --port ${PORT:=9000}
```

instead of just passing in 9000 directly; I assume this is an environment variable. However, trying to run this on Azure gives

```
Error: Error: listen EACCES ${PORT:=9000}
```

which I assume means Azure doesn't recognize ${PORT:=9000} as a valid port.

I know for a fact there's nothing wrong with my client side code because a) I copied it directly from PeerJS's website, and b) everything works correctly when I deployed PeerJS to Heroku. It's only not running on Azure.

Other things I've tried: I edited peerjs in the bin folder to use process.env.PORT instead of what's passed in via the command line, but that didn't work, giving the same EACCES error. When I tried to console.log(process.env.PORT), I got undefined. None of my Google searches have turned up any solutions, although this person ([Custom PeerJs Server giving ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47020721/custom-peerjs-server-giving-err-connection-timed-out)) seems to have a similar error, not on Azure.

Comment: This will be a firewall problem... You will need to open port 9000 in your Azure settings panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Azure App Service doesn't allow us to listen on a customer port. We need to use `process.env.PORT` instead. See [Listen additional port Microsoft Azure Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424405/listen-additional-port-microsoft-azure-nodejs).
2. Azure App Service (on Windows platform) runs on Microsoft IIS. So we need to put the app files to its virtual directory (`D:\home\site\wwwroot`) and no longer need to manually run the app via the Kudu console.

In this case, you first need to install the library under app's root:

```
npm install peer
```

And then create a file named `index.js` or `app.js` with following content and put it to `/wwwroot` folder:

```
var PeerServer = require('peer').PeerServer;
var server = PeerServer({port: process.env.PORT, path: '/'});
```

As @Mikkel mentioned in a comment, PeerServer uses WebSocket protocol, so **Web Sockets** should be enabled in the Azure portal like this:

[image]

You also need to check out [this post](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps) to add a `web.config` file for your app if it has not been created yet.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is going to work, as PeerJS also opens a socket with the client (as well as responding to http requests)

Comment: You mean WebSocket? if so, you'll need to enable it via Azure portal like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459973/websockets-with-socket-io-node-apps-on-microsoft-azure/47466972#47466972). You also need to check [this post](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps) out to add a `web.config` file for your app if it has not been created yet.

Comment: It works when I did it this way, but for some reason, earlier, when I tried to console.log(process.env.PORT), I got undefined. Why does that happen?

Comment: @AaronChen I am glad there is a way to enable the web socket as well - perhaps you could update your answer to make it more complete.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a firewall problem... You will need to open port 9000 in your Azure settings panel.

From the machine itself, open up a browser to http://localhost:9000/ or http://localhost:9000/peerjs and you should see the standard Peerjs server JSON output.

Or if you only have command line, try `curl http://localhost:9000/` or `http://localhost:9000/peerjs`

Comment: How would I do that? All the resources I've found (like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/setup-endpoints) refer to virtual machines, not app services.